# In ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework, how do I lock an account for 15 minutes default? How do I unlock it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do I lock an account for 15 minutes default? How do I unlock it?

Using only ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework

Comment: Locking an account is handled by Windows and/or Active Directory - not ASP.NET MVC or EF .....

Comment: What do you mean by locking account? Is the account data storing in the database? You can add a column `lockStartTime` and set its value when locking the account. Compare this column with current time when you want to check if the account is locked.

Comment: If you are using window identity, it can handled by AD (assuming you want to lock them out of the entire domain). If not you could integrate some authentication middleware and store a lockout date time somewhere to reference for their account.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0